# Liquid error: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll

I am trying a simple Jekyll plugin:

```
class MonthlyArchives < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
    end

    def render(context)
      "#{@text} #{Time.now}"
    end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('monthly_archives1', Jekyll::MonthlyArchives)
```

When I try to run it in page as follows:

```
{% monthly_archives1 %}
```

I get Liquid error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0). Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you give us a backtrace? (eg showing us which line is the problem)?

Comment: also 'monthly_archives'  != 'monthly_archives1'

Comment: @Taryn : I corrected type. Can you tell me how to get backtrace ? Because Jekyll automatically won't give me one.

Comment: You should be able to find it in your logfiles.

Comment: Any ideas about which log file ?

Comment: depends on your environment. it'll most likely be: './log/<environment>.log'

Comment: I am running Ubuntu. There is no environment.log in /var/log. Tried cat * | grep Liquid , no output :(

Comment: It shouldn't be in var/log, but in your local rails directory.: "#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/#{RAILS_ENV}.log" (note, the name of the logfile will be the environment that you are running - not literally "environment" ;)

Comment: The RAILS_ROOT and RAILS_ENV are both empty

Comment: There is no rails server. Its Ruby generating content for Jekyll - a static web site generator

Comment: Aha... my apologies - I guessed Jekyll was just some kind of plugin. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had any chance to build something with Liquid, but the [Jekyll wiki page about building your own plugins](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Plugins) has the whole class surrounded with *module* before registering that

```
module Jekyll
    ...your code...
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('monthly_archives1', Jekyll::MonthlyArchives)
```

that might be an issue.